# How to use VBA to convert a cell content in a table in Word into an image?

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell

I have a few large tables in Word; each table has two columns and many rows. I need to convert each table cell (may have text and equations) in the second column to images. The following is my VBA code:

```
Sub AllCellsToPic()
Dim I, J As Integer, equation As Cell
For J = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
  For I = ActiveDocument.Tables(J).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set equation = ActiveDocument.Tables(J).Cell(Row:=I, Column:=2)
        equation.Range.Select
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
  Next I
Next J
End Sub
```

The code does convert each cell into an image, but the image has borderlines on the top, bottom and left, and the equation number on the right is cut off, as below:
[image]
This actually is the same as what you get when in Word you copy the entire cell and paste as a picture. 
The first line in each cell is blank. If I only select manually from the second line, the image looks fine. How should I change the VBA so that the image does not have the borderlines and includes the equation number on the right? Also, is it possible to export each image as a separate file using VBA? Thanks!

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem with the whole cell not being pasted. Is the row extremely wide? The border issue is easy, just turn borders off before copying, then turn them back on.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thank you John. The cell width is about 7''. Turning off/on does solve the border issue, but the equation number on the right is still missing. I use Office 365. Could this problem relate to the version I use?

Comment: Please check whether the pasted cell is extending past the margin of the Word document. If it's pasting at the same size as the original, you may not have enough page width.

Comment: Thanks John. You are right. The problem is the cell width. After I reduce the page margins and the problem goes away.